# How do I fix question marks inside black diamonds?

Tags: php

I execute this code sending an id to the api and it won't return. My output is question marks inside black diamonds like this "!t �U�ӆ�`�?��L��������9�cf�/�-HIƅ���8��C���J)���W :*�>^@x����]A��گ>�~-� ���V���n��k���N�%���m. � κ6'�#�M��o�1t\�W�d�cs V�`�X�<�H ������o� "

here is my code

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://5sim.net/v1/user/check/' . $id,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language: tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'Connection: keep-alive',,
    'Host: 5sim.net',
    'Referer: https://5sim.net/',
    'sec-ch-ua: "Not_A Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="120", "Google Chrome";v="120"',
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1",
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'X-XSRF-TOKEN: 2393b8e8-2f15-410e-a384-536c6fed6972'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);
    $data = json_decode($response);
```

and my output is this : !t �U�ӆ�`�?��L��������9�cf�/�-HIƅ���8��C���J)���W :*�>^@x����]A��گ>�~-� ���V���n��k���N�%���m. � κ6'�#�M��o�1t\�W�d�cs V�`�X�<�H ������o�

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are we talking about [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/2943403)?  Did you try checking the results directly through postman (without your php/system configurations being a factor)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending this header:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
```

So the server is compressing the response, given that you claimed you support it.

Curl does not scan your custom headers looking for encoding options. If you want to instruct it to handle compression, you need to use the `CURLOPT_ENCODING` option to explicitly tell it. From [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> `CURLOPT_ENCODING`
>
> The contents of the "Accept-Encoding: " header. This enables decoding of the response. Supported encodings are "identity", "deflate", and "gzip". If an empty string, "", is set, a header containing all supported encoding types is sent.

Otherwise, you'll need to check the response headers and deflate response body yourself.

In fact your headers contain some redundant data (e.g. `Host`, which is handled automatically by Curl) that, if wrong, can break the request.